# Are questions under the "mixer" tag more appropriately asked in a different exchange?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked [a question about mixers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/117673/what-are-the-most-common-uses-for-stereo-channels-on-a-mixer) here which got many replies and no comments calling it off topic.  Since then I have found the Sound Design exchange which seems like a more appropriate exchange for mixer questions.  However, both exchanges have a "mixer" tag.

Is it preferred that mixer questions are asked in one exchange over another?  Or more generally speaking, when multiple exchanges share a tag, is there a way to determine the preferred exchange on which to ask a question under that tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that question is on topic, and more relevant here than it would be on Sound Design.

Sound Design is aimed more at the creation/design of sounds and soundscapes, so the mixer questions there are around how to use mixers for that, whereas the mixer questions on this site are more focused around use in performance.

All Stack Exchange sites have a detailed page on what is and isn't in scope, as well as guidance on how to ask a good question - just click on the question mark in the top bar.

Answer (score -1):

Music P&T SE has some areas where it naturally overlaps with Music Fans and Sound Design. While I agree that we should move off-topic questions to appropriate sites, I'd like to point out a devil's advocate counter argument:

Sound Design and Music Fans site are smaller and less active than Music P&T, and many of the most active (and competent) users actually come from our site. Possibly one is more likely to obtain a useful answer on our site than on the other two, even if the question is off-topic.

Comment: It's not a very good argument IMO. A counter I may offer is there's a lot of musical technology knowledge on SO so why ask here? And if SO got a question that would be perfect here and off-topic on SO, why would they migrate it with that mind set? I also want to point out we should __not__ answer off-topic content as that's how you get more off-topic content.