# Convert "What are the most common uses for stereo channels on a mixer?" to community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

The question [What are the most common uses for stereo channels on a mixer?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/117673/70803) is one we might normally close, being a "list question". But it's clearly popular and valuable. I wonder if it would be well served by converting it to a community wiki.

---

Related question: [Are questions under the "mixer" tag more appropriately asked in a different exchange?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3786/70803)

Comment: Maybe the title would be better changed to something like "What are the benefits of a stereo channel over 2 mono channels?"  That was the intent of the question.  It's got so many views now that I'm hesitant to change the title though.

Answer (score -1):

> The question..is one we might normally close, being a "list question".

I rarely get much sympathy around here for suggesting that we need to be careful about casting aspersions on all questions that might be characterised as list questions. But what can I say: I'm ineducable, and I'm going to do it again...

*We need to be careful about casting aspersions on all questions that might be characterised as list questions!*

A large number of on-topic questions here could be written in a way that sounds like they could be asking for a list, or could have a valid answer in the form of a list. For example

- "How can I do X?" can always be written as "What are some ways to do X?", without really being a substantially different question.
- "Why does Y happen?" can be written as as "What are some reasons why Y happens?".
- Even when there's no plural in the title, or mention of a list, a question might be likely to be replied to with a number of elements arranged in the form of a list. [Is shredding on bass possible?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/117392/is-shredding-on-bass-possible) is an example - I answered in the form of a list as I do quite often, because IMO there's a list of things to consider.

A similar question to the one mentioned could be phrased as "Should I choose a stereo channel or two mono channels for my specific case X?". But you could argue that "What are the most common uses for stereo channels on a mixer?" is actually asking the question in a more general, and therefore more community-minded way.
'
As far as I can see, there's no general prohibition of 'list questions' in our help center. There's a mention of *subjective* list questions, but arguably it's the subjectivity that's the real problem there. The topic of common uses for stereo channels doesn't seem particularly subjective, by the standards of this site.

> I wonder if it would be well served by converting it to a community wiki.

There are various thoughts on what constitutes a good community wiki question - some of them are that any individual might only be expected to provide a partial answer, and that answers might be expected to change as time moves on. The first point might be somewhat applicable here, but there are many other questions asked here where a 'complete' answer is unlikely that we still don't Community Wikify.